# How to make sure a smaller substring doesn't get found inside a larger substring (i.e. a word containing "she" doesn't also flag as having "he")

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I hope I worded my question right.

Basically here's what I'm trying to do: Using a List of pronouns, I have to search for words in a separate list that are made up of two of said pronouns (i.e. "youthy" would be found and printed out after matching both "thy" and "you")

What's going wrong: I'm find the words sure, but the problem here is like the example in the title. When I run the program I'll have results that match two substrings inside one another (i.e. "Yourn is popping up because it's seeing "You" and "Your" or "Our").

I'm using Python 3.x, and this is one section of a problem for a homework assignment, and is the last one I have left to do. I've tried quite a few solutions so far but none  have worked. One was making a copy array that gets checked instead and removing each element as it goes along. Another was using a blank list that had the first match added to it, which would then have the next match compared to it just in case the next one was inside the first match. But no matter what I try I keep getting bad matches mixed in or nothing gets printed because the counter no longer goes up.

The pronoun list I have to work with:

```
pronouns = ['thou', 'thee', 'thine', 'thy', 'i', 'me', 'mine', 'my', 'we',
            'us', 'ours', 'our', 'you', 'yours', 'your', 'he', 'him', 'his',
            'she', 'her', 'hers', 'it','its', 'they', 'them','theirs','their']
```

Example word list:

```
wordList: = ['a', 'youthem', 'thyme', 'adathey', 'bathem', 'writmaker',
'writmaking', 'youngling', 'your', 'yourn', 'yours', 'youse', 'youthsome', 
'youthtide', 'youthy', 'zygomaticosphenoid', 'zymite', 'zymosimeter', 
'zymosthenic', 'zythem']
```

My code:

```
    for line in wordList:
        hasBoth = 0 #Counter where the program will not print a word
                    #if it does not equal 2.
        for pnoun in pronouns:
            #print(str(hasBoth) + " " + str(nounCopy)) #Test to check what's
                                               #triggering some of the words.
            if hasBoth == 2: #Breaks the loop if both words are found.
                break
            if pnoun not in line: #If there's no match, do nothing and
                                  #continue
                continue
            elif pnoun in line: #If match, add 1 to counter and continue
                hasBoth += 1
                continue
            else: #just in case
                break

        if hasBoth == 2:
            print(line + "\n") #Print the line that was a success
            hasBoth = 0 #reset the counter
            continue
        elif hasBoth != 2: #If no match, just reset the counter and move on
            hasBoth = 0 #reset the counter
            continue
        else:   #Another one for just in case something else happens
            print("Ya'll broke somthin")
            break
```

The expected result is supposed to be:

```
youthey
thyme
youthy
```

But the actual result is the whole list minus the first element.

Comment: are you allowed to use packages? hahaha because this is an assignment and I'm assuming you're supposed to learn the logic and control flow than depend on packages HAHAHA

Comment: There's nothing saying I can't! But I think teacher has to be able to run it without having to install anything xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pronouns = ['thou', 'thee', 'thine', 'thy', 'i', 'me', 'mine', 'my', 'we',
            'us', 'ours', 'our', 'you', 'yours', 'your', 'he', 'him', 'his',
            'she', 'her', 'hers', 'it','its', 'they', 'them','theirs','their']

wordList = ['a', 'youthem', 'thyme', 'adathey', 'bathem', 'writmaker',
'writmaking', 'youngling', 'your', 'yourn', 'yours', 'youse', 'youthsome', 
'youthtide', 'youthy', 'zygomaticosphenoid', 'zymite', 'zymosimeter', 
'zymosthenic', 'zythem']


return_list = []

for pronoun in pronouns:
    for word in wordList:
        replaced = word.replace(pronoun, '')
        boolean = replaced in pronouns and pronoun in word and word not in return_list
        return_list.append(word) if boolean else None
```

this is a solution off the top of my head. I honestly would make this much cleaner but for readability sake, this will do. My assumption is that the word has to *exclusively* be made of 2 pronouns (i.e. `youthey` can't be classified as having 3 pronouns `you`, `they`, `the`). With that in mind:

1. loop through each pronoun
2. remove all traces of the pronoun in current loop
3. if the new word (`replaced`) is still in the `pronouns` list, that means it's exclusively made up of 2 pronouns
4. You also have to be careful of words that are, by themselves, pronouns (`your`, for example) hence the need for `pronoun in word` boolean
5. Lastly, in order to avoid duplicates, check if the `word` is in the `return_list`. You could technically just end the logic before #5 and then just flatten return_list but that's an added step that you could have avoided with a small addition in the boolean.

`return_list` is exactly what you want it to be `['thyme', 'youthy', 'youthem']`

Comment: Man thank you so much, this was making me pull my hair out. I see what I was doing wrong now as well!